# AlertDialog not working properly after second presentation to the user

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

it seems that my `AlertDialog` is not working when formed and showed for the second time. I catch PickFsDone in main program and it seems like it doesn't get set to true when I call function below for the second time...

Any advice, what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance,
regards,
Rob.

> Edit: have added more details in code. The main program stops in loop
>   waiting for Dialog, although Dialog has ended sucessfully on screen.
>   This happens second time, first time it works... Adding
>   dialog.dismiss() deosn't help.

```
    public void createListAlertDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Pick a Sampling Rate");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(SampleRates_Str.toArray(new String[SampleRates_Str.size()]), SampleRates_Index,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        SampleRates_Index = item;
                    }
                });

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        PickFsDone = true;
                    }
                }

        );

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();
}

public void PickSampleRate ()
{
  final boolean Wait;

  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //Create the alert dialog
      createListAlertDialog();
    }
   }
  );
}

// In Main Program :
PickFsDone = false;
PickSampleRate();

//Wait for Dialog to finish
while (true) {
    if (PickFsDone) break;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading this post can help you : [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you dismissed or cancelled the dialog before creating a new one?

Comment: Thanks for hint. I've added dialog.dismiss() after PickFsDone = true; but it seems not to help. The problem is that I want indefinitely for PckFsDone to become true in main program and then proceed. But it seems that second time PickFsDone is not set tu true...